# mysql text value with apostrophe not showing up correctly

Tags: php, forms, addslashes

I'm inserting the following TEXT value into MySQL using..

$groupname = addslashes($_POST['groupname'];

When getting the value from Mysql I'm using

$name = $row['groupname'];

echo $name;

And this show correctly as "Mr. Davis's Group"

but when this value in added to a form as

then I pass the value to another page, and retrieve it as

$name = $_POST['groupname'];
echo $name;

it show up as "Mr. Davis" keeping everything before the apostrophy.

??No clue why, i've tried adding stripslashes($_POST['groupname']; and same thing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input name='groupname' type='hidden' value='$groupname' />
```

Will generate:

```
<input name='groupname' type='hidden' value='Mr Davis's Group' />
                                                     ^----
```

At the indicated spot, the browser's parser will see the 'end' of the `value=`, followed by some unknown attribute `s` and a broken attribute `Group '`.

To embed this type of text in a form, you need to use `htmlspecialchars()`, which will convert any HTML metacharacters (`<`, `>`, `'`, `"`) into their character entity equivalents, so they can be safely embedded in a form.

`addslashes()` is a deprecated method of "safely" adding something into a database. It will not make something safe to embed in HTML.

Comment: Ah, your powers of observation are great. +1

Comment: where exactly would I use htmlspecialchars, before putting into the DB or after?

Comment: when retrieving the data. Never store the html-encoded data in the database, as you never know what you'll need the data for afterwards. If it's going into a spreadsheet, then the HTML encoding would be useless and you'd just have to undo it.

Comment: I know this is old, but for completeness: In this case, you will probably need to use the flag `ENT_QUOTES`: `htmlspecialchars($groupname, ENT_QUOTES)`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the text encoding of your input webpage. Match your db charset - use utf-8.