# MySQL value with apostrophe now showing up in textarea

Tags: php, html, forms, character

I have inserted the following TEXT value into mysql..

```
$_POST['groupname'] = "Linda's Group";
$groupname = $addslashes($_POST['groupname'];
```

then retrieve it like this..

```
$groupname = $row['groupname'];
```

when I echo it it shows up correctly as "Linda's group"

but when I put it into..

```
echo "<input name='groupname' type='hidden' value='$groupname' />";
```

it shows up as "Linda", only show text before the apostrophe

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `value=\"$groupname\"` will take care of single quotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql text value with apostrophe not showing up correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114275/mysql-text-value-with-apostrophe-not-showing-up-correctly)

Comment: can you update your question to explain what `it` refers to when you echo `it`, and also what you mean by `echo ""; ` (this should NOT echo "Linda" and I presume you actually echo something else). It may sound pedantic, but programming is pedantic.

Comment: @fosco, your suggestion works.  Kind of a pain because I'm going to have to change a lot of code. Any thing I can change in php.ini to do this site wide?

Comment: @Dobot: this is an exact dupe of your previous question. You'll have to fix up your code, because PHP can't/won't do this for you automatically.

Comment: its not an exact dup, on my last post i forgot to mention that I was trying to echo the value into an input text field.  so yeah, i'm new to stackoverflow, I didn't know they had "question police" on here. I tried to update my previous question but was unable to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want to send a string to the browser, use `htmlspecialchars($string)`.

Replace that with:

```
echo "<input name='groupname' type='hidden' value='" . htmlspecialchars($groupname, ENT_QUOTES) . "' />";
```

... and remove the `addslashes()` call.

Also, make sure you always use `mysql_real_escape_string($string)` when inserting string values in a MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your single quote before you use it in your HTML. This is because your attribute values are surrounded by single quotes.

If you didn't escape the quote, the generated HTML is:

```
<input name='groupname' type='text' value='Linda's group' />
```

This is not valid. What you need is:

```
<input name='groupname' type='text' value='Linda&#039;s group' />
```

You can get that by calling [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
echo "<input name='groupname' type='hidden' value='" . htmlspecialchars($groupname) . "' />";
```

This also prevents XSS attacks. Otherwise someone could enter `'/><script type="text/javascript">alert("omg hax!")</script><br'` for example, and you would get an alert on your page.

Comment: be more specific. where and how?

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape content before displaying it on a web page. your markup reads:

try:
    htmlspecialchars($dataToEscape, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' false)

without this you are vulnerable to XSS.
consider `Linda'><script src='evil.js'></script>s Group` this example:

```
<input name='groupname' type='hidden' value='Linda'><script src='evil.js'></script>s Group' />
```